# Как покрыть тестами строки, которые идут после определения наличия функции?

Tags: php, функции, codeception, codecoverage

Как покрыть красные строки тестами, если функция `getallheaders` существует? Может быть, можно ее как-то удалить или что-то еще сделать с ней? По сути, функция `getallheaders` существует только в Apache, а в Nginx ее нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin зачем вам текст этого кода? Что там искать собираетесь? Тут как раз именно демонстрация покрытия тестами, а не вопрос по написаю кода.

Answer (score 0):

Первое, что пришло в голову: написать новый тест, в котором перед вызовом ассертов, определить собственную функцию:

```php
public function myTest()
{
    function getallheaders() { ... }
    // ...
    // asserts
}
```

По крайней мере, это не даст выполниться первому условию внутри `getAllHeaders()`.